# Match rows and and remove values from a cell if condition is met

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` such as

```
data = data.frame(plot = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                  family = c("Fab", "Fab", "Fab", "Pip", "Fab", "Mel", "Myr", "Myr", "Fab"),
                  species = c("Fab", "Fab", "sp 1", "sp2", "Fab", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp1"))
```

What I'm trying to do is, if character names in columns `family` and `species` match by row, keep the name on `family` and add `NA` to the respective `species` column cell. I was trying to loop but it doesn't seem like a worthy way to do this since my `data` is pretty big...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base R, you can assign `NA` to the species column after filtering for your use case:

```
data <- data.frame(plot = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                   family = c("Fab", "Fab", "Fab", "Pip", "Fab", "Mel", "Myr", "Myr", "Fab"),
                   species = c("Fab", "Fab", "sp 1", "sp2", "Fab", "sp3", "sp4", "sp5", "sp1"), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data[data$family == data$species, ]$species <- NA
data
#>   plot family species
#> 1    1    Fab    <NA>
#> 2    1    Fab    <NA>
#> 3    1    Fab    sp 1
#> 4    2    Pip     sp2
#> 5    2    Fab    <NA>
#> 6    3    Mel     sp3
#> 7    3    Myr     sp4
#> 8    3    Myr     sp5
#> 9    3    Fab     sp1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(species = case_when(species == family ~ NA_character_, 
                             TRUE ~ species))

# A tibble: 9 × 3
   plot family species
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
1     1 Fab    NA     
2     1 Fab    NA     
3     1 Fab    sp 1   
4     2 Pip    sp2    
5     2 Fab    NA     
6     3 Mel    sp3    
7     3 Myr    sp4    
8     3 Myr    sp5    
9     3 Fab    sp1
```